# Prove that : $\operatorname{inf}{\alpha >0 , \mu {f>\alpha }=0}= \operatorname{sup}{\alpha >0 , \mu {f>\alpha }>0}$

Tags: calculus, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Consider $(X,\Sigma, \mu)$ an arbitrary measure space

$f$ positive and measurable function

Prove that :

$$\operatorname{inf} (\{\alpha >0 , \mu (\{f>\alpha \})=0 \})=\operatorname{sup} (\{\alpha >0 , \mu (\{f>\alpha \})>0 \})$$

I don't know how I started in the prof its difficult to me 
Bcz I don't when and how I use the identity ?

Comment: Do you mean $\inf_{\alpha > 0} \mu(f > \alpha) = 0$? Or how is your notation to be understood?

Comment: @blat yes Sir , thank you very much!